# Which Android IDE for NFC development?

Tags: android, ide, nfc

For a living, I code C / C++ for embedded systems. For fun, I have coded JS, PHP, Python & more. Two or three years ago, I developed some small apps for Android, just to see what it was about.

Now, someone has offered me a side-gig, developing an NFC app for Android.

As I understand it, the choice is pretty much between Android Developer Tools and Android Studio (although I am happy to hear of others).

I have a slight personal aversion to Eclipse, and all else being equal that would be a tie-breaker, but it won't otherwise weigh in my decision.

It might be that I am asking how mature the newcomer, Android Studio, is. And also, whether Google are pushing Android Studio over Android Developer Tools, so that it might be more future proof?

However, the actual question (finally) of a s/w recommendation is - which IDE will make me most productive when developing an NFC app for Android?

Off the top of my head, thinks to think about are code completion, function parameter help,refactoring, the debugger, unit testing ... any more?